# How to retrieve correspoding form element from dojo event object?

Tags: dojo

If there is a html form with a button, with normal html, we would be able to retrieve form element from the onclick event object as follows.

```
ev.target.form
```

As Dojo contains a its normalize event object, how can we retrieve event generated form element when a button is clicked ? (I require this as my dom tree contains duplications of same form element)

Thank you,
nimp

Answer (score 0):

```
dojo.connect(dojo.byId("formsContainner"), "click", function(evt){
   dojo.stopEvent(evt); // assuming you don't want to actually go to a new page

   var n = evt.target;
   while(n.tagName != "form"){
      if(n.tagName == "body") break;
      n = n.parentNode;
   }
   if(n.tagName == "form"){
      myFormMethod(n);
      return;
   }
   console.error('no form for button - clicked on something else')
});
```

Comment: Thank for the reply, my form is not having a predefined id. so basically what I need is that to retrieve randomly generated form id, which is assigned by dojo, from the evt object